# Deserializar um arquivos XML e inserir em uma database MySQL

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Um salve para a galera aqui,
Como ler arquivos XML para que os dados possam ser inseridos em uma base de dados [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). O problema está em ler o XML e deserializar, uma vez que o retorn está em branco, pois a inserção no Banco de dados está tranquilo. Estou usando [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) como [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), As estrutura do arquivo é a seguinte, sendo que authors pode ter vários, assim como *keywords*

```
<records xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.doaj.org/schemas/doajArticles.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <record>
    <language>por</language>
    <publisher></publisher>
    <journalTitle></journalTitle>
    <issn></issn>
    <publicationDate>2013-04-18</publicationDate>
    <volume>6</volume>
    <issue>1</issue>
    <startPage />
    <endPage />
    <doi>00.123456/ebrasilis.v6i1.XXX</doi>
    <publisherRecordId />
    <documentType />
    <title language="por"></title>
    <title language="por" />
    <authors>
      <author>
        <name></name>
        <email />
      </author>
    </authors>
    <abstract language="por" />
    <abstract language="eng" />
    <fullTextUrl format="pdf">http://www.periodico.ebras.bio.br/ojs/index.php/ebras/article/view/ebrasilis.v6i1.XXX</fullTextUrl>
    <keywords language="por"></keywords>
    <keywords language="eng" />
  </record>
</records>
```

O código em [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) é:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<Serializable()>
<XmlRootAttribute("records")>
Public Class Registros
    <XmlArrayItem("author")>
    Public Property authors As List(Of author)
    Public Property language As String
    Public Property publisher As String
    <XmlElementAttribute("journalTitle")> 
    Public journalTitle As String
    Public Property issn As String
    Public Property publicationDate As String
    Public Property volume As String
    Public Property issue As String
    Public Property startPage As String
    Public Property endPage As String
    Public Property publisherRecordId As String
    Public Property documentType As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property abstract As String
    Public Property fullTextUrl As String
    Public Property doi As String
    Public Property keyword As keywords

    Public Sub New()
        authors = New List(Of author)()
    End Sub

    Public Class author
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property email As String
    End Class
    Public Class keywords
        <XmlArray("keywords")>
        <XmlArrayItem("keyword")>
        Public keyword As New List(Of String)
    End Class
End Class
```

Script:

```
Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Registros))
Dim deserialized As Registros

Using reader As New StreamReader(sFileXML)

    deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader)

    If deserialized Is Nothing Then
        DivMsg.InnerHtml = "&lt;div class='alert alert-warning'&gt;Objeto está Vazio&lt;/div&gt;"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox(deserialized.journalTitle) 
    'usado apenas para testar e retorna em branco assim como todas as variáveis 
End Using
```

Comment: qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a dúvida é como deserializar os dados, pois com os códigos acima, obtenho a Msgbox em branco, ou seja, não há nenhum retorno.